# Web Scraping in R: Table with NO ID

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, html-table

I am new to web scraping in R, and I am trying to web scrape some election data: https://www.elections.alaska.gov/results/18GENR/data/results18.htm

It seems that the data is given in several tables without IDs. I want to collapse some of the tables together. Basically I want to have information on each State senate and state house race with the total votes and the candidates.

Where do I start?

I have been using inspector gadget.

This gives me a list of all of the office titles:
`office = page2 %>% html_nodes(".tr:nth-child(3) td , th") %>% html_text()`.
Which is kind of helpful, but ultimately I want each row to be the observation for each office election.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the CSV source, like this:

```
> library(readr)
> df<-read.csv("https://www.elections.alaska.gov/results/18GENR/data/results.txt", header=FALSE)
> df
```

To group in different ways maybe try dplyr or data.table, like this:

```
> library(data.table)
> tElec<-data.table(read.csv("https://www.elections.alaska.gov/results/18GENR/data/results.txt", header=FALSE))
> tElec$V6<-NULL # remove last always-blank column
> tElec[V1 %like% "HOUSE DISTRICT 12"]

                   V1                             V2   V3     V4    V5
1: HOUSE DISTRICT 12   Number of Precincts for Race   NP  Total      7
2: HOUSE DISTRICT 12  Number of Precincts Reporting   NP  Total      7
3: HOUSE DISTRICT 12              Registered Voters   NP  Total  15488
4: HOUSE DISTRICT 12                  Times Counted   NP  Total   8292
5: HOUSE DISTRICT 12               Tilton, Cathy L.  REP  Total   6099
6: HOUSE DISTRICT 12              Jeffers, Stephany  DEM  Total   1993
7: HOUSE DISTRICT 12                       Write-in   NP  Total     25
```